# Firebase onDataChange on null object reference

Tags: nullpointerexception, firebase

I have the simple code to get the group members as:

```
ValueEventListener getGroupMembersListener;

presentGroupMembers = myFirebase.child("groupMembers").child(groupID);

        presentGroupMembers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(getGroupMembersListener);

        getGroupMembersListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot groupMemberSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    if (!groupMemberSnapshot.getKey().equals(preference.getUserSyncID(getApplicationContext()))) {
                        Member groupMember = new Member();
                        groupMember.setUserUID(groupMemberSnapshot.getKey());
                        groupMember.setUserName(groupMemberSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                        mGroupMembers.add(groupMember);

                        Log.v("InvitingFriendsToGroups", "Group member userName is: " + groupMemberSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                        Log.v("InvitingFriendsToGroups", "Group member user ID is: " + groupMemberSnapshot.getKey().toString());
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.v("InvitingFriendsToGroups", "Firebase Error: " + firebaseError.toString());

            }
        };
```

Yet I continually receive the error:

```
03-11 21:57:56.995 9100-9100/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.android.appv2, PID: 9100
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener.onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot)' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.firebase.client.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:144)
                                                     at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:56)
                                                     at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
                                                     at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6840)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I have been using Firebase for several weeks and this error has never appeared, nor on my far more complex queries.

What could be incorrect with this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving this code

```
presentGroupMembers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(getGroupMembersListener);
```

to after

```
getGroupMembersListener = new ValueEventListener() {
```

block, check if it works and let me know if it works now.

Comment: Your answer worked but i did not understand the logic. In launcher activity onStart it did not work for the first time but else where it works.